# Only give permission to modify/delete a list item to the user that created it

Tags: permissions, security, list-item

I have created a simple Hyperlink list on which everyone can create, edit and delete items.

Now I need to add some more restrictive permissions similar to the following:

- Only the users that created an item can delete and modify it.
- All other users can only View the items but cannot delete/modify it.

Can anyone give me any hint for solving this?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest steps would be to give contribute permissions to the users who can create, modify and delete items in this list. Rest, just give NT Authority Authenticated Users read access on the list.

You need to do this by modifying list settings > list permissions.